# VBA excel copy cell comment and past it onto a new sheet without using clipboard?

Tags: vba, excel

Hello my goal is to copy a comment, of a cell without having to use the clipboard (or all that added code :D) im still new to VBA so sorry for any errors :D

I was trying to use this code below it works great on cells but im not sure if it works on comments to

```
Sheets("Dump").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("K1")
```

i try to change it around a bit but it gave me an error "application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Sheets("Dump").Range("A1").CopyComment Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("K1").AddComment
```

ty for any help one can give

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Cell `A1` comment being copied to `B1`

```
Sub Testit()
    Range("A9").Copy
    Range("B9").PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
End Sub
```